# How to plot the graph created in redisgraph?

Tags: graph-visualization, redisgraph

I have created a graph in redisgraph.I want to visualise the graph directly from redisgraph without using another library because again I have to create same graph in that library.How to plot the graph directly from redisgraph?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Comment: Check redisinsight - https://redislabs.com/redisinsight/